# Proof attempt for collection of all open intervals being a basis of $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Show that the collection of all open intervals $\{(a,b)\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology:

My attempt:

---

I believe we want to show two things:

1) All elements, $x\in\Bbb R$ are contained in some basis element:

$\forall x\in\Bbb R$ $x\in(x-1,x+1)$ $\square$

2) If $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ then there is some $B_3$ such that $x\in B_3$ and $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$

If $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ and $B_1=(a_1,b_1)$ and $B_2=(a_2,b_2)$ then $B_1\cap B_2 = (\max(a_1,a_2),(\min(b_1,b_2))$, if we let $B_3=(\max(a_1,a_2),(\min(b_1,b_2))$ then $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$ and clearly $x\in B_1\cap B_2=B_3 \iff x\in B_3$

---

Is it acceptable that I simply let $B_3=B_1\cap B_2$ by construction? Or should my $B_3$ be a proper subset, i.e. not equal?

Also is my proof acceptable in general?

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown is that the collection of open intervals is a basis for *some* topology, but not that it is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.  If $X$ is a topological space, then we say that a collection $\mathcal B$ of open sets of $X$ is a *basis* (of open sets) for the topology if every open set in $X$ can be written as a union of open sets drawn from $\mathcal B$.

Equivalently, $\mathcal B$ is a basis if the open subsets of $X$ are precisely those sets $U$ such that for every $x\in U$ there exists $V\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in V\subset U$.

Using the second version, it should be clear that the collection of open intervals in $\mathbb R$ is a basis for the standard topology.

---

Where do the two conditions you talked about come in?  Well, if $X$ is a *set*, then it can be shown that a collection $\mathcal B\subset\mathcal P(X)$ of subsets of $X$ is a basis of open sets for *some* topology on $X$ if and only if it satisfies the two conditions you mentioned:

1. For every $p\in X$, there is $V\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in V$.
2. For every $U,V\in\mathcal B$, and any $q\in U\cap V$, there is $W\in\mathcal B$ such that $q\in W\subset U\cap V$.  Equivalently, $U\cap V$ can be written as the union of sets drawn from $\mathcal B$.

But the topology might not be the one you are interested in.  For instance, the singleton collection $\{\mathbb R\}$ satisfies conditions (1) and (2) (for $X=\mathbb R$), and it is indeed a basis of open sets for a topology on $\mathbb R$ (the indiscrete topology), but it is not a basis for the standard topology.  Similarly, $\mathbb P(\mathbb R)$ satisfies the conditions for a basis, but it is a basis for the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$, not the standard topology.  Finally, the collection $\mathcal B$ of all half-open intervals $[x, y)$ satisfies (1) and (2), but it is a basis for the *half-open interval* topology, which is not the same as the standard topology (indeed, $[0,1)$ is not open in the standard topology).

It's a good idea to work through the proofs of the claims I have made.  Namely, that:

- Show that the two versions of a definition of a basis for a topology given above are equivalent.
- If $X$ is a topological space, and $\mathcal B$ is a basis of open sets for the topology on $X$, show that $\mathcal B$ satisfies (1) and (2).
- If $X$ is a set, and $\mathcal B\subset\mathcal P(X)$ satisfies (1) and (2), show that the collection of all unions of sets contained in $\mathcal B$ is a topology on $X$.

Let us know if you have any trouble with those.

Comment: Did you mean $p\in V\subset U$?

Comment: @Ali Thank you, fixed now.

Comment: @JohnGowers could you explain a little more about how one would show that the open intervals for a basis for the standard topology? I can see how showing a basis for a topology doesn't imply a basis on the standard topology (the singleton example you gave makes sense), but I can't think how to show that the open intervals DO form a basis under the standard topology. Would it be a matter of showing that it forms a basis under the second definition in your answer above?

Comment: @TopherNoms You need to show that the open sets of reals (in the standard topology) are precisely those sets that can be written as a union of open intervals. If you think about the definition you're familiar with for an open set of reals, then it should be fairly straightforward to show that this definition is equivalent to saying that the set is the union of open intervals.

Comment: Would it be enough to pick an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ of the form $(c,d)$, and then saying that as $U$ is open in the reals, then for all $x \in U$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $x\in V = (c+\varepsilon, d - \varepsilon)\in \mathcal{B}$ and $V \subset U$?

Does that satisfy the definition that you have provided in your answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @TopherNoms Not every open $U \subset \mathbb R$ is of the form $(c,d)$. If it is, then you can just take $V=(c,d)$, since $(c,d)$ is already an open interval. What is the definition of open set in $\mathbb R$ that you are familiar with?

Comment: @JohnGowers That the open set, $S$, doesn't contain all of its accumulation points, or that for each $x$ in the set, there is exists an open ball containing $x$ that is strictly contained inside $S$

Comment: @JohnGowers Ohhh I have to deal with the case where we have the union of disjoint open sets?

Comment: @TopherNoms Not containing all its accumulation points means that $S$ is not closed, which is not the same thing as saying that it is open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122713/discussion-between-john-gowers-and-tophernoms).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have taken a long winded approach in part 2. Suppose $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$. That means $B_1 \cap B_2 \neq \phi$. If you say $B_1=(a_1,b_1)$, $B_2=(a_2,b_2)$ then it must hold that $a_2 < b_1$. So $B_1 \cap B_2 = (a_2,b_1)$.

Comment: Some steps are missing. You have to assume that $a_1 \leq a_2$ and that $B_2$ is not a subset of $B_1$. Or you could just follow the OPs proof.